# Copy directories and files of an Amiga IDE HDD

Tags: permissions, mount, disk

I am trying to make a copy of an old IDE Amiga disk with all files/directories. I have a Windows 10 system and the PC doesn't see or access the drive. I have connected the drive with an IDE-SATA connector. Now I have made a bootable Ubuntu flash drive, boot from it, and use it as the trial of Linux. I now see the Amiga drive and was able to mount it with:

```
sudo mount -t affs /dev/loop6 /mnt
```

But it says it is the write-only mount.

I can ls the drive and see the directory structure, but can't go into the directories or copy the dirs and files. The permission is denied.

I am totally new to Ubuntu and Googled a lot but can't find a proper solution.

What I want is to copy the directories and the files within to e.g. the documents folder of Linux, so I can later save them to a USB stick.

How can I manage the rights of the Amiga disk? And how to copy all of the content?

Comment: Please add into the question the actual error message.

Comment: This will make a dump: `sudo ddrescue -r3 /dev/sdb amigadisk.img logfile`  but you will need to find out the device id 1st. sdb is a guess from me. And `kpartx -av amigadisk.img -r` can be then used to map the contents to a virtual image that you can then mount as a loop device,

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!

The command ddrescue is not available on my Ubuntu it sais. I have made an image of the HDD in the disk section of Ubuntu and tried your code with kpartx but it gives me the following error:

/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver. Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.167 (2019-11-30) and kernel driver (unknown version) device mapper prequisites not met.

Comment: install it with `sudo apt install ddrescue` probably (cant test that ;)) otherwise use https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/

Comment: I did all the things as said, but still get the above error about permission at using the command kpartx....

Comment: Maybe it has also something to do with the fact that the image is a backup of the second partition of that Amiga HDD?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.amigaforever.com/kb/15-113 on copying Amiga files.  Still, if you can mount and see the disk contents, you should be able to copy things. One issue might be filenames with unusual chars (for Ubuntu), but as root, just tar all the amiga files, and move the tar archive to where you want, untar at some point...

Comment: I have tried both WINUAE as Amigaforever but they were not be able to make a disk image. The disk is running fine in an Amiga 1200 system and the .img exported from Ubuntu was without errors. Just a permission problem I guess....  As I checked the imagefile made in Ubuntu it sais the owner is root. It there a way to set the owner to myself?

Comment: So far no luck with teh Amiga HDD. Anybody any suggestions? What I really want is to mount as administrator (all rights) user the Amiga HDD, so I can browse and backup te files under Ubuntu.

Comment: I connected nativly the Amiga with a 0 modem cable and was able to transfer the files to my PC.